# Динамические графики QCharts

Tags: qt, qml

Всем привет! 
Очень требуется помощь по графикам. Есть программа, которая гоняет байты по протоколу модбас. Есть устройство, с которого считываются разные данные и токи. Именно по токам надо рисовать график. Сейчас я использую графики QCustomPlot. Но если я начинаю двигать график, приближать/уменьшать масштаб графиков, то программа вылетает. Если же график не трогать вообще, а только смотреть на него, то программа вылетать не будет. Хоть даже если 10 000 пакетов программа получит. Что весьма печально.

Прошу помощи, готов заплатить.

Я над проектом работаю пол года и сроки начинают поджимать. Я без сил уже. Я начал разбирать QChart'ы, но не могу въехать как их сделать динамическими. Чтобы можно было двигать графики. И чтобы они сами двигались, когда приходят пакеты с токами.

Буду очень благодарен всем кто сможет мне помочь в этом проекте.